# C# dll (Threaded) from VBA

Tags: c#, vba

I have a C# dll with methods that should be called 
 1. from its UI for some users and 
 2. VBA for some users

I set the project 'register of COM interop', registered with Regasm, referenced from VBA and created the object, called the method from VBA module. This worked fine both from VBA & its UI.

Now, I had to change the method to run in a separate thread for some other UI processing.
Now the VBA code does not work. There is no error. It simply returns the module but nothing is processed.

Is there a way to wait for the C# thread to complete in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are registering the COM component for both 32 and 64 bit.

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm "Contoso.Interop.dll" /tlb:Contoso.Interop.tlb /codebase Contoso.Interop

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm "Contoso.Interop.dll" /tlb:Contoso.Interop.tlb /codebase Contoso.Interop

Edit: Change as required and as per framework version.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Also, is there way to pass structures from vba to C# as a parameter?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. If you expose the C# type as a Com object you may be able to pass that type.